# Combine Multiple pdfs with a new page with text between each

Tags: linux, command-line, pdf, imagemagick, pdftk

I've read through and tried multiple posts on similar topics and none satisfied my purpose.

I have multiple pdfs which are project reports for each week of a 16-week project and are titled `Week1.pdf`, `Week2.pdf`, ..., `Week16.pdf`.  I'd like to combine them into a single large pdf with a single page between each new report. The single-page between each report must have a title like "Week 2" between the pdfs of Week1 and Week2 reports, "Week3" between the reports of Week2 and Week3, and so on.

I understand that the ImageMagick command `convert` can be used to create single pdf pages for the page breaks and `ps2pdf` package can later be used to combine all of them together. Is there a simpler or easier solution where I create such pdfs and combine them in a single shot?

Any suggestions/workarounds are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any experience with python? [This tutorial](https://realpython.com/pdf-python/#how-to-merge-pdfs) here explains how to do what you want at the "merge pdf" section.

```python
# pdf_merging.py

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

def merge_pdfs(paths, output):
    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()

    for path in paths:
        pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(path)
        for page in range(pdf_reader.getNumPages()):
            # Add each page to the writer object
            pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(page))

    # Write out the merged PDF
    with open(output, 'wb') as out:
        pdf_writer.write(out)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    paths = ['document1.pdf', 'document2.pdf']
    merge_pdfs(paths, output='merged.pdf')
```

You then just need to create a pdf page with what you want in between, and stitch them together with the above script.

There are plenty of methods to create a pdf page with your text, the easiest one is LaTex generation, but also any Word/OpenOffice let's you  export your document as a PDF.